# How to delete perticular lines and its nearby lines in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file named `file.txt` and it contains several lines containing string "NaN". How can I delete lines containing "Nan" and one line before and after it. I know `sed －i '/pattern/d' file.txt` can delete the matched line, but how can I delete neaby lines of the matched line.
Best regards

Comment: Please do share samples of input and expected output in your question to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: `ed` is probably a more suitable command for tasks like this, though I am not sure how to handle the case where `NaN` is the first or last line in the file. `printf 'g/NaN/-,+d\nwq\n' | ed file.txt`. (When there is no previous or next line for `-` or `+` to match, the script fails.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a most inelegant solution, but works.  Perhaps, it will anger a UNIX guru to come and provide a real answer.

```
grep 'Nan' -n -C 1 target_file.txt | awk -F '[-:]' '{print $2}' | sed '2d' | paste -d, - - | sed 's/$/d/' > del_lines.sed && sed -f del_lines.sed target_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

fyi, The word "perticular" is misspelled, its "par-" like in golf!